# How to assign a color to a WKT layer with leaflet? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, leaflet, wkt

I want to change the color of the path lines on a leaflet map. By default the color is blue and I would like to make it red.

I was inspired by the examples here: https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore but nothing to do I can not used from customerLayer or modify the layer.

Here is my function :

```
    function AddRoad(str_wkt) {
            var routing;
            routing = JSON.parse(str_wkt);
            var test = omnivore.wkt;
            road = test.parse(routing);
            map.addLayer(road);
    }
```

str_wkt is a WKT string which is used to draw a route on a map, for now everything works very well but impossible to change the style of the road

If someone has a solution, I'm very interested !

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I could find the answer alone, I share for the next !

```
function AddRoad(str_wkt) {
       var routing = JSON.parse(str_wkt);
       road = omnivore.wkt.parse(routing);
       road.eachLayer(function (layer) {
            if (layer.feature.geometry.type === 'LineString') {
                layer.setStyle({
                    color: #FF0000, 
                    weight: 4,
                    opacity: 0.75
                });
            } else {
                console.log('unknown geometry type');
            }
       });
       map.addLayer(road);
    }
```

road is a layer that reads the string WKT str_wkt.
Subsequently, we change the style of the layer road and we define a color, a weight and an opacity.